# How to make a series of parallel(asynchronous) API requests with dynamic URLs in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, httprequest, request-promise

How to call HTTP requests asynchronously in Node JS. I have 3 major challenges as below.

- Requires to call asynchronously.
- Request URL is dynamic.
- Avoid using loops.

The below method is used to call single endpoint.

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: "http://api.example.com"
}
```

const response = await request(options);

[RequestPromise NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

---

In order to call asynchronously, I have used [parallel-http-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-http-request) as below.

```
request.add({
    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 
    method:'post',
})
.add({
    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2', 
    method:'post'
})
.add({
    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3', 
    method:'post'
});
```

---

Both the above methods support static number of API requests which cannot be dynamically handled.

E.g. When using [parallel-http-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-http-request) it needs to be add `.add({` keyword in the JS code and this will not support dynamic URL parameters.

**Is there any other way to achieve this task?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: **use romise.all()** . Ref:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Also, `parallel-http-request` does not support only static number of requests, just call add in a loop

Comment: @Harsha did you get a chances to look that the answer ? does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all` and wrap all the request promise in an array.

```js
 await Promise.all([
  request({
      url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 
      method:'post',
  }),
  request({
      url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2', 
      method:'post'
  }),
  request({
    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3', 
    method:'post'
  })
]);
```

Also, since is a possibility of promise getting reject. wrapping a `try-catch` is a must.

```js
try {
  await Promise.all([
    request({
        url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 
        method:'post',
    }),
    request({
        url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2', 
        method:'post'
    }),
    request({
      url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3', 
      method:'post'
    })
  ]);
} catch (e) { 
  // handle if any one of the request is failed
}
```